What is the meaning of Fr 0,20
In Louis Bacheliers The Theory of Speculation he often uses “Fr number”. I have no idea what it means.

Could it be French Franc? A long-gone pre-Euro currency. "Since every quarter a coupon for 0.75fr is detached .."

Yes it is a franc.

Both F and Fr were used as abbreviations for the French Franc, the ISO code for FX trading was FRF https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_franc Also, in France the comma serves as the decimal point, so 0,20 or 20 centimes would be written 0.20 in the USA.
